# How to check select contains default selected option or not?

Tags: jquery

I want to check if any select is submitting default selected option. If so then the submit button event will change the select drop down background color  otherwise the the button will normally allow for submit. Here is the source code:

```js
      checkEmpty();

      function checkEmpty() {
        $('form').find('input').on('blur', function() {
          if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
          } else {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
          };
        });
      };

      $('button#button1').on('click', function() {
        $('form').find('input').each(function() {
          if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
          } else {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
          };
        });

        //This code 
        $('form').find('select').each(function() {

          if ($(this).val() == '0') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
          } else {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
          };
        });

      });

      $('#employeeid,#number').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
          return false;
        }
      });

      $('#employename').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which < 97 /* a */ || e.which > 122 /* z */ ) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });
```

```css
.bs-example {
  //font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
}
.typeahead,
.tt-query,
.tt-hint {
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100%px;
  line-height: 100%px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  //width: 100%;

}
.twitter-typeahead {
  width: 100%;
  display: block !important;
}
.typeahead {
  background-color: #84e184;
}
.typeahead:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0097CF;
}
.tt-query {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
}
.tt-hint {
  color: #999999;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  //width: 422px;

}
.tt-suggestion {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  padding: 3px 20px;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
  background-color: #0097CF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">Test</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="acode">ID</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5 " id="empid">
              <div class="  input-group ">
                <span class="input-group-addon "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 
                <input class="form-control " list="employeeid" name="employeeid" id="employeeid" placeholder="Enter ID">
                <datalist id="employeeid">
                </datalist>
                <span class="input-group-btn">           
                              <button type="button" id="search" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" style="background-color:red;">
                              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search "  aria-hidden="true" ></i></span>
                </button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employename" id="employename" placeholder="Enter Name">
              <span id="errmsg2" class="errmsg"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Enter Number">
              <span id="errmsg2" class="errmsg"></span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Month</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <select name="langOpt[]" id="langOpt">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>Select Month</option>
                <option value="ALL">All</option>
                <option value="JAN">January</option>
                <option value="FEB">February</option>
                <option value="MAR">March</option>
                <option value="APR">April</option>
                <option value="MAY">May</option>
                <option value="JUN">June</option>
                <option value="JUL">July</option>
                <option value="AUG">August</option>
                <option value="SEP">September</option>
                <option value="OCT">October</option>
                <option value="NOV">November</option>
                <option value="DEC">December</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" onclick="" id="button1" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
      checkEmpty();
      function checkEmpty(){
        $('form').find('input').on('blur', function(){
          if($(this).val()==''){
            $(this).css('background-color','red');
          } else {
            $(this).css('background-color','transparent');
          };
        });  
      };

      $('button#button1').on('click', function(){
    ok=true;
  $('form').find('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()==''){ 
            $(this).css('background-color','red');
   ok=false;
          } else {
            $(this).css('background-color','transparent');
          };
        });
  
  //This code 
  $('form').find('select').each(function(){
  
    if($(this).val()==null){  
            $(this).css('background-color','red');
   ok=false;
   
          } else {
            $(this).css('background-color','transparent');
          };
        });
     return ok;
      });

      $('#employeeid,#number').keypress(function(e){
          if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
             return false;
          }
      });

      $('#employename').keypress(function(e) {
          if(e.which < 97 /* a */ || e.which > 122 /* z */) {
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>      
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
      <style type="text/css">
         .bs-example{
         //font-family: sans-serif;
         position: relative;
         margin: 100px;
         }
         .typeahead, .tt-query, .tt-hint {
         border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
         border-radius: 8px;
         font-size: 12px;
         height: 100%px;
         line-height: 100%px;
         outline: medium none;
         padding: 8px 12px;
         //width: 100%;
         }
         .twitter-typeahead {
         width: 100%;
         display:block !important;
         }
         .typeahead {
         background-color: #84e184;
         }
         .typeahead:focus {
         border: 2px solid #0097CF;
         }
         .tt-query {
         box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
         }
         .tt-hint {
         color: #999999;
         }
         .tt-dropdown-menu {
         background-color: #FFFFFF;
         border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
         border-radius: 8px;
         box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
         margin-top: 12px;
         padding: 8px 0;
         //width: 422px;
         }
         .tt-suggestion {
         font-size: 12px;
         line-height: 12px;
         padding: 3px 20px;
         }
         .tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
         background-color: #0097CF;
         color: #FFFFFF;
         }
         .tt-suggestion p {
         margin: 0;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body >
      <div class="container"  >
         <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary"  >
               <div class="panel-heading" >
                  <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">Test</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" >
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="acode">ID</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 " id = "empid" >
                           <div class="  input-group ">
                              <span class="input-group-addon "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>         
                              <input class="form-control " list="employeeid" name="employeeid" id="employeeid"  placeholder="Enter ID">
                              <datalist  id="employeeid">        
                              </datalist>
                              <span class="input-group-btn">           
                              <button type="button" id="search" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" style="background-color:red;">
                              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search "  aria-hidden="true" ></i></span>
                              </button>    
                              </span>         
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">                                                               
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employename"  id="employename" placeholder="Enter Name" >        
                           <span id="errmsg2" class="errmsg"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Number</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">                                                               
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number"  id="number" placeholder="Enter Number" >        
                           <span id="errmsg2" class="errmsg"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Month</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">                                                               
                            <select   name="langOpt[]"  id="langOpt" >
           <option value="0" selected disabled>Select Month</option>
        <option value="ALL">All</option>
        <option value="JAN">January</option>
        <option value="FEB">February</option>
        <option value="MAR">March</option>
        <option value="APR">April</option>
        <option value="MAY">May</option>
        <option value="JUN">June</option>
        <option value="JUL">July</option>
        <option value="AUG">August</option>
        <option value="SEP">September</option>
        <option value="OCT">October</option>
        <option value="NOV">November</option>
        <option value="DEC">December</option>        
       </select>
                        </div>
                     </div>
      
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                           <button type="submit"  onclick="" id="button1" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>                            
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sree, it worked However,is it possible to keep both of these features?

Comment: Yes. I have edited my answer to prevent form submit .Please check

Comment: please replace your old  `$('button#button1').on('click', function(){` to new . don't add my code seperately

Comment: hi @Sree, i did the replace but still not working if keep  **disabled** attribute.thanks

Comment: Wait @Sree, you removed **disabled** attribute !

Comment: But @Sree.i told that ,i want both of these feature disabled + select check.Otherwise your first solution is simple and correct than new one.thanks

Comment: @user5005768 : Finally Check my answer now :) just change `if($(this).val()==0){` to `if($(this).val()==null){`

Comment: Thank god . Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple check to see if the selected month equals the default month.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
   var month= $(#DropdownID option:selected).val();
    if(month== "Select Month")
    {
     alert("Please select a Month");
     return false;
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".